# Spring Access Control

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I working on Spring MVC app. The app funcionality is accessible through ReST API which jsp containing ajax logic consume. I am using spring security with defined roles (USER, COMPANY, ADMIN). Methods use requestMapping with responseBody such as:

```
www.app.com/auth/{userId}/request/{requestId}
```

It, of course, support GET for obtaining resource and POST for its creating or updating.
The problem is that after succesful login with, for example, userId = 1 I want GET request with requestId = 99. But when I run WebDev client for Chrome, I can also access another resource with easy request in format

```
www.app.com/auth/5/request/{requestId}
```

So basically, I can access resources, which I am not allowed to see. I hope you got the idea, where I am heading.

My question is - What  is the best approach to secure this?
I was thinking about storing logged user Id (Integer) in session and comparing it everytime request for resource  is made, but it seems to me that I am pulling the wrong end of rope :)

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look into the [Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) section of the spring security documentation.

Example copied from the documentation:

```
  @PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
  public void doSomething(Contact contact) {
     ..
  }
```

This would check if name of the contact is equal to the name of the currently logged in user.

Using this this feature you can build much more sophisticated access rules than you could do with simple roles. However, this does not exclude using roles. You can still keep roles for basic security checks.

Comment: So, the solution I see now is: I have a method with some RequestMapping, ResponseBody, declaration is SaveRequest(String requestName, String requestContent) and I have to add parameter "who has called" (probably unique name - username - of logged person) the method for example String invoker and using @PreAuthorize("#invoker == authentication.name"). Is this the right attitude?